# Can Kotlin Exposed be integrated with Spring Data JPA?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, kotlin-exposed

I would like to integrate Kotlin Exposed into a Kotlin application that is already using Spring Data JPA.  The problem I have is that only want to use one Transaction Manager for my application, but currently I have to have two (one for JPA and another for Exposed).  Is there a way to only have one Transaction Manager?

Comment: No longer trying to find an answer to this.  I've decided to use jOOQ instead of Exposed.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work with `kotlin-exposed` library before, but based on your question 
,Just you have to create your own `transaction-manager` bean. After that spring will use your bean, and you need to configure `kotlin-exposed` to use it.
sample:

```kotlin
    @Primary
    @Bean("appTransactionManager")
    fun appTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("appEntityManagerFactory") appEntityManagerFactory: LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
    ): PlatformTransactionManager {
        return JpaTransactionManager(eccTransactionManager.getObject()!!)
    }
```